# Preparing DOM in compile to build for loop directive fails to load in window.print()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, printing

I'm trying to use the AngularJS to print the defined div contents need to populated to print function. Where all the 
data is loaded by `$scope.printDetailedData` which is passed to object function (`printElement`) but not appear in `$window.print();` print popup is initiated.

```
 $scope.printDetailReport = function (data) {

 $scope.printDetailedData = formatTimeToLocal(data); 
 printElement($window.document.getElementById('detailPrint'));   
 $window.print() ; };

  function printElement(elem) {
         var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

  var $printSection = $window.document.getElementById('printSection');

  if (!$printSection) { $printSection =
 $window.document.createElement('div');

   $printSection.id = 'printSection';   
 $window.document.body.appendChild($printSection);
     }

  $printSection.className = 'visible-print';

   $printSection.innerHTML = '';  $printSection.appendChild(domClone); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you leverage on CSS to do that? Just construct your print section normally like any other div in your Angular template and use CSS to tell the browser that it will show only on print. Use the following CSS code and add the .sprintSection class to your print-only div.

```
@media screen {
  .printSection { display: none; }
}

@media print {
  .printSection { display: block; }
}
```

Comment: Ya, but here i need to control dynamic Div contents to show in print block. That's y im using like this, but contents in "#detailPrint" is now loaded in print preview window.

Comment: I don't fully understand why you have to do it by means of low-level DOM manipulation as long as you've got the Angular template mechanics and 2-way data binding, but I suggest you wrap your call to printElement(...) within a `$scope.$apply` call like this:
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        printElement($window.document.getElementById('detailPrint'));
    });

Comment: And here we need to populate 2 diff div contents for printing by button click function for each div contents simply having list of Grid values in it with pagination controls. Is not displaying on print preview.

Comment: have you tried making it work in BOTH screen and print mode, when you click the button? see if the elements get injected in screen mode, then see how you can show them only in print mode, via css

Comment: Ys Stefan, the list of grid elements injected successfully in screen mode by pagination control UI. At bottom we are havin 'Print' button when its clicked need to show all the elements without pagination in print screen mode. Tht's im looking for it.

Comment: By ur $scope.$apply implemented it throw some of issue like, 
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Comment: yeah, it makes sense. you'll get this error if it's not called within a non-Angular asynchronous function call. given that you're not actually touching the scope, it won't solve anything.
Anyway, it's hard to tell what the problem is unless you paste in the template code too. Alternatively, you could try and isolate this issue into a small snippet that reproduces it and put it in a jsfiddle. That would make it easier for anyone here to debug the problem.